# firebase blaze plan took money directly after upgrading to it and didn't wait to the end of the month

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, billing, google-cloud-billing

I have upgraded my firebase project to blaze plan . I read that the project will take money from me at the end of each month but what happened with me is that when I upgraded the app it took money directly and didn't wait for the end of the month

Comment: I would recommend contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/) for assistance with this.

Comment: Billing questions are off topic for Stack Overflow.  As suggested in the prior comment, contact Firebase Support directly.

Comment: So, did you find a proper explanation for that?  @MohamedHasan